# Connection Refused localhost:9999 java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, datadog

I'm using Datadog to collect metrics from Kafka running on my localhost.
When I run the -info command on my Datadog agent this is the error I get for Kafka. Any ideas whats causing this?

```
kafka
    -----
      - instance #kafka-localhost-9999 [ERROR]: 'Cannot connect to instance localhost:9999 java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: \n\tjava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]' collected 0 metrics
      - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks
```

Comment: From a terminal/console window, what does telnet localhost 9999 do?  If port 9999 is open/available, then you should get a blank screen.  Use Ctrl-] to get to the telnet prompt and then exit.

Comment: Yes, im not able to telnet on my mac on any of the ports.. from 9000-- 9999 any ideas how to open up the port from terminal?

Comment: I'm not mac savvy, but I would google, locate and disable the firewall on the mac first.  Then try telnet.  If that doesn't work, then google iptables and selinux...the mac is essentially linux under the covers.  So you'll need to read a little on networking, ports, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you have not set your JMX_PORT for kafka from where your datadog agent can listen information abouot the metrics.

Restart your Kafka with the following additional key/value pair parameter:
'JMX_PORT=9999'

$ JMX_PORT=9999 ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties

Answer (score 0):

This error essentially means that the Datadog Agent is unable to connect to the Kafka instance to retrieve metrics from the exposed mBeans over the RMI protocol. This error can be resolved by including the following JVM (Java Virtual Machine) arguments when starting the Kafka instance (required for Producer, Consumer, and Broker as they are all separate Java instances)
please

[Please read this article](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/faq/troubleshooting-and-deep-dive-for-kafka/)